# How does EME protect copyright for DRM?

Tags: javascript, encryption, video, webapi, eme

I am trying to explain the Encrypted Media Extensions (EME) API on [my programming reference website](https://webcodingcenter.com/web-apis/Encrypted-Media-Extensions).

After getting the encryption and decryption to work on a video file, I started to wonder how the EME API is going to protect the copyright of a video. What if the user simply downloads the movie file and intercepts the license key? Won't the user be able to decrypt the video too?

Comment: EME is new to me. Do you have ideas (possibilities) about how a license key can be intercepted by the user? My understanding is that it happens as a silent process between browser (server) and hardware and the user side is not aware of any information (what/when/how it is used). For the user it just works...